# can't get the results of select query in an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sqlite

I have a problem when trying to store the results of a select query into an array with java script . 
the problem is that inside the function the array is containing the right values but outside it's empty , even when i used a global var it's still empty !!!

```
db.transaction(function (transaction) {
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM Question where idEnq=" + idEn;

    transaction.executeSql(sql, undefined, function (transaction, result) {
        var res = document.getElementById('results');
        res.innerHTML = "<ul>";
        if (result.rows.length) {
            for (var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
                var row = result.rows.item(i);
                ch[i] = new qu(row.id, row.text, row.type);
                res.innerHTML += '<li>' + row.id + '&nbsp;' + ch[i].text + '&nbsp;' + ch[i].type + '</li>';
            }
            tablo = ch;
        } else {
            alert("No choices");
            res.innerHTML += "<li> No choices </li>";
        }

        res.innerHTML += "</ul>";
    }, onError);
}); // here the ch and the tablo array are empty
```

Comment: You really need to start indenting your code properly!!!

Comment: Don't put `idEn` directly in the query text, that is what bind variables (the second argument for `executeSql`) is for.

Answer (score 5):

You are using asynchronous functions. Anything that wants to use the data "returned" by those functions need to be in the callback. Of course you can assign this data e.g. to a global variable, but that variable will only have the value after the callback has run (asynchronously).

Comment: sorry but I'm new to JS and I don't know how to use the callback !!

Comment: Move your code that is currently after the `db.transaction(...)` call inside the callback, i.e. after `res.innerHTML += "</ul>";`

Comment: this code is already inserted into a function that returns the array , do i have to add the callback parameter as follow :               function GetQuest(idEn,callback) {...... ...............         return tablo;} and then what ?

Comment: I followed the answer given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933877/returning-array-from-javascript-class-method-to-a-script/10472933#10472933  but an error occurs saying 'Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined' so what should I do ??

Answer (score 0):

you're new so have look here http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/02/JavaScript-Function-Tips-and-Tricks.aspx
there's a part talking about calling JavaScript Function asynchronously