# Return value from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, return

I have a section of code in my `$(document).ready(function() {}` that reads: 
`getInitial(len);` 
Where len is an integer.

```
function getInitial(number){
    number--;
    if(number < 0) return
    var $items = $(balls()); 
    $items.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $container
        .masonry('reloadItems')
        .append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items, true );
    });
    getInitial(number);
}
```

Notice the line that reads: `var $items = $balls(());`

That is defined as:

```
function balls(){
    $iterator -= 1;
    if($iterator < 0){
        var $boxes = $( '<div class="box">No more games!</div>' );
        $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes, false );   
        return; 
    }
    var imgPreload = new Image();
    var ret; 
    imgPreload.src = 'scripts/php/timthumb.php?src='+$test[$iterator][2]+'&q=100&w=300';
    $(".imgHolder").append('<img src="'+imgPreload.src+'"/>');
    //console.log(imgPreload);
    $(".imgHolder").imagesLoaded(function(){
        ret = '<div class="box" style="width:18%;">'
            +'<p>'+$test[$iterator][1][2]['name']+'</p>'
            +'<img src="'+imgPreload.src+'"/>'//Replace this with the one below when timthumb is whitelisted
            +'<div id=boxBottom>'+Math.floor($test[$iterator][0]*100)+'%</div>'
            +'</div>';
    });
    console.log(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

My question is how can I get `ret` from the imagesLoaded() method inside of the `balls()` function to return to the `$items` inside of `getInitial()`?

I hope there's no more confusion.

Comment: Well, it's not even *in* the function. So far the return isn't in a function at all. But since it's asynchronous, returning something from that function isn't going to help anyway. Without further context it's difficult to help.

Comment: @JTorres Yeah, sorry if that confused anyone.

Comment: It seems like the callback function of `imagesLoaded` is asynchronous, in which case you can't return the value immediately.

Comment: @JTorres I make almost no assumptions about the context of someone else's code when it's clearly incomplete. Particularly with asynch code, context is critical. For example, Ricardo's answer ignores the asynch nature and returns the HTML immediately--that *may* be okay, but it happens before the image is loaded, which is very different behavior.

Comment: @DaveNewton It was clear enough to me, why else would you have it in a function, I think you're being too picky. It's pretty clear that the question is how come ret doesn't contain the right values when that return statement is reached

Comment: @JuanMendes Yeah, I guess I just prefer complete questions that provide enough information to answer. I know, it's weird, right?

Comment: @DaveNewton We have a saying in Portuguese: `For a good 'understander', half a word is enough`. Funny I'm the one saying it, since I'm the one usually complaining about questions that aren't well asked.

Comment: @JuanMendes Guess I'm just stupid.

Comment: I'm going to completely update my OP to more accurately reflect my request.  I am not knowledgeable enough yet with Javascript to know that evidently my question was a bad one.  Please hold.

Comment: @DaveNewton I do find it hard to believe that you didn't understand what the question was asking considering your rep is above 47K. It's like French people that won't talk to Americans in Paris even if they do speak English, just because the American didn't try to speak French. Ooops... I digress.

Comment: @Adola did you try my solution?

Comment: @JuanMendes I will not pretend asking incomplete questions is appropriate, regardless of how you disparage me for believing it. Look at my first comment: you still think I didn't understand the question? I think it's pretty clear I did, but that the question needed to be asked more clearly. Ricardo's answer might work just fine--might not even *need* the async part. I'm not going to guess--just how I roll.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not disparaging you... I leave a comment to say that the question can be better all the time . However, if I can see what the user is asking, I'll answer the question along with some comments that say, please improve your questions, you're more likely to get answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton, I hope this update has cleared up my question.  I didn't think I needed all the extra information.

Comment: @JuanMendes The question wasn't answerable with any accuracy as asked, because there's no context. The purpose matters in this case, and the edited question highlights that the whole thing could be done in a much more straight-forward manner.

Comment: Hah, not to sound forward, but...I assume that means you know the answer to my updated question?  

This has been plaguing me for MANY stackoverflow questions now, and I think I'm on the verge of fixing it.  it's this issue that's the problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton For sure it can be done in a much better way. That code is craptastic, sorry Adola.

Comment: @Adola: Updating my answer to reflect your update...

Comment: @DaveNewton After all my rants, I must agree with you, I assumed the rest of the code would make more sense than it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your function runs asynchronously, you need a callback function. You cannot have it return a value. Return values by passing callbacks.

```
function getInitial(number){
    number--;
    if(number < 0) return
    // Can't do the following, it's asynchronous
    // var $items = $(balls()); 

    // Do this instead
    balls(function(html) {
        var $items = $(html);
        $items.imagesLoaded(function(){
            $container
            .masonry('reloadItems')
            .append( $items ).masonry( 'appended', $items, true );
        });
        getInitial(number);
    })
}

function balls(callback){
    $iterator -= 1;
    if($iterator < 0){
        var $boxes = $( '<div class="box">No more games!</div>' );
        $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes, false );   
        return; 
    }
    var imgPreload = new Image();
    var ret; 
    imgPreload.src = 'scripts/php/timthumb.php?src='+$test[$iterator][2]+'&q=100&w=300';
    $(".imgHolder").append('<img src="'+imgPreload.src+'"/>');
    //console.log(imgPreload);
    $(".imgHolder").imagesLoaded(function(){
        callback('<div class="box" style="width:18%;">'
            +'<p>'+$test[$iterator][1][2]['name']+'</p>'
            +'<img src="'+imgPreload.src+'"/>'//Replace this with the one below when timthumb is whitelisted
            +'<div id=boxBottom>'+Math.floor($test[$iterator][0]*100)+'%</div>'
            +'</div>');
    });
}
```

Callbacks is how you *return* values from asynchronous functions

There are probably still problems, the code is very confusing. But this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: @JTorres It does answer the question. Your answer doesn't work. There is **no** way to return a value (synchronously) from a function if you're getting the value asynchronously. Callbacks are the only way to *return* values from async functions.

Comment: I did try this, but it ended up being the same question as my OP, I've updated my OP actually in an attempt to clarify my question better.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is the correct answer, at least as far as could be determined from the original question. +1 to offset.

Comment: @Adola **You did not try this** I can guarantee you that. Your example is still calling `balls()` and not passing a callback function. Re-read what the answer is saying and update it to using asynchronous code.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks man, even after our friendly discussion, you still showing love :)

Comment: @JuanMendes I am fairly sure I"m doing it right.  

Just for clarity: I changed: 
`function balls(){` to `function balls(callback){`
And also changed in `function getIntial(number){`: 
`var $items = $(balls());` to `balls(function(contents){
   var $items = (contents); 
 });`

Is that correct?  Because if I `alert($items);` I get `[object object]` instead of the string.  

Sorry if I'm not understanding this correctly.

Comment: @Adola No it isn't right... your `getInitial` is recursive, which makes it harder. I'll give it 5 minutes to see if I can come up with the solution

Comment: @Adola: Start with the code in the answer. Remember, there is no way on Earth that you're going to be able to do something like `var items = balls()` because `balls` is asynchronous, you have to use a callback

Comment: @JuanMendes I do believe this is working!  (As in, it now runs, I have to do a lot more testing to see if this solution fixes a different problem; ouside the scope of my OP) 

Thank you very much for your help, i don't _QUITE_ get the code you wrote, but I'll learn it.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Adola if this doesn't work, you should create something on http://jsfiddle.net Makes it a lot easier for others to help. However, your code sample still shows that you don't understand asynchronous functions. Your code sample seems to imply that you think $items would be populated after the call to `balls` That's the main thing you need to understand. You can't rely that everything in the callback in the lines after the call to `balls()`

Comment: @JuanMendes, your right, I do not understand async calls, which is precisely why I asked the question on the first place.  If I DID know, there'd be no reason for me to ask.  I find that continued argument moot.

Comment: @Adola the continued argument is for your sake, are you complaining that I'm trying to help you understand it? That's what I get for investing 30 minutes of my time. Here's another question that answer the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9933877/returning-array-from-javascript-class-method-to-a-script/9933906#9933906

Comment: I wasn't complaining, I'm just saying everyone has been talking about what a bad question it was.  Though I'm grateful, honestly, I just think it's kinda unfair to blame ME for asking a bad question when I didn't know it was so.

Comment: @Adola Asking a good question is an art. If you had understood what I said from my initial answer, then your initial question was good enough. But since you didn't, it wasn't a good enough question. The only way you'll know that your question is incomplete is if we tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var imgPreload = new Image();
var ret = '<div class="box" style="width:18%;">'
          +'<p>'+$test[$iterator][1][2]['name']+'</p>'
          +'<img src="'+imgPreload.src+'"/>'
          +'<div id=boxBottom>'+Math.floor($test[$iterator][0]*100)+'%</div>'
          +'</div>'; 
imgPreload.src = 'scripts/php/timthumb.php?src='+$test[$iterator][2]+'&q=100&w=300';
$(".imgHolder").append('<img src="'+imgPreload.src+'"/>');
//console.log(imgPreload);
$(".imgHolder").imagesLoaded();
return ret;
```

Comment: @JuanMendes The difference is that `ret` receive it's value before load images. On his code `ret` receives it's value after load images, but it has already been returned.

Comment: It does seem like it would work, since there is nothing used in `ret` that is set from the `imagesLoaded` handler. Then why is the OP calling it from `imagesLoaded`?